# Is it possible to use Vuex mapActions inside an exported module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Is it possible to call Vuex mapActions from a separate module that's imported into a component?

I'm trying to standardize a set of functions in a vue.js web app. I'd like to import them into each component and pass some values the to function operate. I'm using vuex to manage state. Currently each component calls these functions each time they're loaded (identically the same).

I'd like to refactor into this into one module and import it into each component as needed. This code uses mapActions as part of it's function. Below are the relevant pieces of code: component, module, vuex action

Vue component:

```
//the imported function call
if (!this.queued){
   timer.updatePage(this.pagination, this.orders);
}
```

the module code (advance.js):

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

let currentComp = {
   name: 'purchase',
   date: null,
   start: false
}

const timer = {
   ...mapActions(['currentComponent']),
   updatePage(pagination, order) {
      currentComp.name = 'nextComponent';
      this.currentComponent(currentComp);
   }
}
export default timer;
```

the vuex code:

```
//in the actions section:
currentComponent({
        commit
    }, comp) {
        console.log(comp);
        commit('setCurrentComponent', comp);
}

//in the mutations section:
setCurrentComponent: (state, comp) => {
        state.currentComponent = comp.name;
        return state;
    }
```

when the component runs the imported function i get:

```
vuex.esm.js?2f62:870 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined
    at Object.mappedAction [as currentComponent] (vuex.esm.js?2f62:870)
    at eval (advance.js?935c:37)
```

when i remove the this from this.currentComponent i get:

```
advance.js?935c:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: currentComponent is not defined
    at eval (advance.js?935c:37)
```

thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: you can merge any vue component either in mixins or by extending - so you dont loose vue scope - or try to `.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapActions` is a shortcut for creating a method that looks something like this

```
currentComponent() {
   this.$store.dispatch('xxx')
}
```

When you call this function, the `this` context is `timer`. Since `timer` does not have a `$store` property, you get the error `Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined`. The quickest way to get around this would be to change the `this` context to the component which does have a `$store` property. You could do this by passing the component as a third property in `updatePage` and binding `currentComponent` to the function.

```
// component code
timer.updatePage(this.pagination, this.orders, this);

// advance.js
const timer = {
   ...mapActions(['currentComponent']),
   updatePage(pagination, order, component) {
      currentComp.name = 'nextComponent';
      this.currentComponent.bind(component)(currentComp);
   }
}
```

I'd recommend using a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) for this type of behavior though.

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';

let currentComp = {
   name: 'purchase',
   date: null,
   start: false
}

const timerMixin = {
   methods: {
       ...mapActions(['currentComponent']),
       updatePage(pagination, order) {
          currentComp.name = 'nextComponent';
          this.currentComponent(currentComp);
       }
   }
}
export default timerMixin;
```

In your component, import the timerMixin and register it as a mixin. Those methods would then be available directly on your component and you can call them with a small tweak to your existing code.

```
if (!this.queued){
   this.updatePage(this.pagination, this.orders);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Mixins appear to be the way to go here.